# Sales Comparison problem, how to apply Chi Square Test or alternatives?

Tags: statistics, chi-square-test, statistical-significance

Lets Say Before Pandemic, the Sales of Product A, B, ,C and D, are 780 , 350 , 250 , 100,
This is an Average of 36 Months , considering 12 months of Pandemic data is ignored, and after pandemic, 730 , 370 , 190 , 130, and this is an average of 24 Months. What would be the best statistical approach to say if the sales and pattern has changed or not ?